# Conv3D model input tensor

Tags: multidimensional-array, pytorch, resnet

I am new to PyTorch and I want to make a classifier for 3D DICOM MRIs. I want to use the pretrained resnet18 from monai library but I am confused with the input dimensions of the tensor. The shape of the images in my dataloader is [2,160,256,256] where 2 is the batch_size, 160 is the number of dicom images for each patient and 256x256 is the dimension of the images.
When I try to run the model I get this error:
**Expected 5-dimensional input for 5-dimensional weight [64, 3, 7, 7, 7], but got 4-dimensional input of size [2, 160, 256, 256] instead**

If I unsqueeze the tensor before feeding it to the model I get:
**Given groups=1, weight of size [64, 3, 7, 7, 7], expected input[1, 2, 160, 256, 256] to have 3 channels, but got 2 channels instead**
Can anybody help me figure this out ?

Comment: Can you show us your model, at least the part (Conv3D?) that causes the error?

Comment: The first Conv3D layer of ResNet is this:
(conv1): Conv3d(3, 64, kernel_size=(7, 7, 7), stride=(1, 2, 2), padding=(3, 3, 3), bias=False)

Comment: Are you not specifying a "channels" parameter for your input.   According to the doc., "Input shape:
5+D tensor with shape: batch_shape + (channels, conv_dim1, conv_dim2, conv_dim3) if data_format='channels_first' or 5+D tensor with shape: batch_shape + (conv_dim1, conv_dim2, conv_dim3, channels) if data_format='channels_last'."

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the channel dimension for each slice (which is one for MRIs).
Eg your input should be of shape (2,1,160,256,256)